# ESP32 preferences library: what is the correct use of .end()

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

Following [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-save-data-permanently-preferences/) on how to use the Preferences library it is not clear when to call `preferences.end()`.

Do I need to call this as soon as I've finished reading or writing, or can I wait until I put the ESP32 to sleep? Will I loose all the changes if the ESP32 looses power and `.end()` hasn't been called?

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/tutorials/preferences.html#workflow